# Tkinter and Turtle Display Objects - How They Interact

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

After a lot of research and experimentation, I believe I have found a minimum viable program for an OOP-based Tkinter app using turtle graphics. The code is below.

I would like to understand more fully exactly how this code works.

There are a whole bunch of display objects whose exact function I am having trouble understanding.

TL;DR: is this correct:

> `RawTurtle` needs a `screen`. The screen is a `TurtleScreen`. The `TurtleScreen` needs a `Canvas`. The `Canvas` needs a `root`. The `root` is an instance of `tk.TK()` and is part of a `Frame`.

?

More details:

- `root` - it's an instance of `tk.Tk()`. What is this actually creating in terms of a visual object?
- `tk.Frame` - is the root "on" the frame or the frame "on" the root? It looks like the constructor of `tk.Frame` is being called with `root` as an argument. What is their relationship?
- `master` - the same as root, no? If so, why are different names often used in the same program?
- `Canvas` - Why do we need it? What is it's relationship to `TurtleScreen?`
- `TurtleScreen` - what is that than?
- I've also seen `RawTurtle.getscreen()` - how does this fit in?

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master.title("Raw Turtle")
        self.pack()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
        self.canvas.config(width=600, height=200)
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        screen = turtle.TurtleScreen(self.canvas)
        screen.bgcolor("black")
        tur = turtle.RawTurtle(screen, shape="turtle")
        tur.color("green")
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `Tk()` initializes the GUI environment, and returns your initial window to put widgets in - this is often called `root`.  A `Frame` is a generic widget for containing other widgets - the one in your code is pointless, as it contains nothing.  The first parameter to this, and all other widgets, is the parent widget that is to contain it; this is commonly referred to as `master`.  A `Canvas` is a specialized widget for drawing graphics, no part of the turtle module would be possible without using one.

Comment: BTW: you can even use `class App(tk.Tk):`

Comment: @jasonharper you could put your comment as answer.